# Why does Spark Cassandra connector fail with NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.getIndexes()Ljava/util/List?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Help me to resolve the following error

```
scala> println(rdd.first)
...
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.getIndexes()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.getIndexMap(Schema.scala:193)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchPartitionKey(Schema.scala:197)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:239)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1(Schema.scala:238)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:247)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:246)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:246)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:252)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:249)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:249)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:51)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:146)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1272)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1312)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1311)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    at <init>(<console>:61)
    at .<init>(<console>:65)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

cassandra-2.2.3, spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6, spark-cassandra-connector-1.5.0, cassandra-driver-2.1.5.

Comment: >cassandra -2.2.3   >spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6    >spark-cassandra-connector - 1.5.0     >cassandra-driver - 2.1.5

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem! Could you share your version configuration? Would be very helpful...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved . The problem was i didn't follow the Version Compatibility . And this [Solution](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) solved my problem . Thanks for replays.

Comment: Can you share the version(s) you had and what you use currently?

Comment: Hi,  please check the link for solution http://datadotz.com/apache-spark-cassandra-read-and-write/